# ReferenceError: fav is not defined

Tags: ember.js

I am a noob with emberjs and I am stuck at the issue for a while now. I created an itemController with the variable fav, but it keeps saying that it is not defined.

My index.html snippet looks like this:

```
<table class='table'>
                  {{#each model itemController='hotel'}}
                  <tr><td>
                      {{#if fav}}
                      <h4>{{title}}
                          <button {{action 'rmFav'}} type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span>
                          </button>
                      </h4>
                      {{else}}
                      <h4>{{title}}
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right" {{action 'putFav'}}>
                          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty"></span>
                          </button>
                      </h4>
                      {{/if}}
                      <p> {{description}} </p>
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
                  </td></tr>
                  {{/each}}
              </table>
```

and my app.js has the following snippet related to the itemController:

```
App.HotelController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

  actions: {
        putFav: function(){
            this.set(fav,true)
        },
        rmFav: function() {
            this.set(fav,false);
        }
    }
});
```

UPDATE: Just a clarification, I have an array of objects in json format in app.js file, and each object in it contains fav attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with `HotelController` you are referencing an undeclared variable `fav` in `this.set(fav,...)` you need to change to a string, `like this.set("fav",...)`:

```
App.HotelController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

  actions: {
        putFav: function(){
            this.set("fav",true);
        },
        rmFav: function() {
            this.set("fav",false);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: omfg! I just spent 3 hours trying to debug this. Thanks a lot! You are a life-saver.